# Jersey server sent event

Tags: maven, server-sent-events, media-type

I tried to use jersey server sent event with maven. But when i use eventSource to make request, i have an error

```html
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventOutput, and Java type class org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventOutput, and MIME media type text/event-stream was not found.

 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:284)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:927)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:875)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:829)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:247)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:210)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1476)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventOutput, and Java type class org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventOutput, and MIME media type text/event-stream was not found.
```

And here is my code java

```js
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventOutput;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.OutboundEvent;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.SseBroadcaster;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.SseFeature;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.open.ome.core.entity.item.ModifiedFeature;
import com.open.ome.core.entity.user.UserRole.UserRoleString;
import com.open.ome.facade.util.ConstantUrl;
import com.open.ome.facade.util.UtilFacadeException;
import com.open.ome.service.exception.OmeServiceException;
import com.open.ome.service.item.MapService;

@Path("/modified")
public class ModifController {
 
 /**
  * Service.
  */
 @Autowired
 private transient MapService mapService;
 
 private static final java.util.Map<Long, SseBroadcaster> listSseBroadcaster = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
 
 /**
  * Permet d'enregistrer une modification effectuée sur un feature
  * 
  * @HTTP 403        l'utilisateur connecté n'a pas les droits nécessaires 
  * 
  * @param request  la requête reçue.
  * @param id       identifiant de la carte à récupérer
  * @return         identifiant de la carte
  */
 @GET
 @Path("/modifiedfeature" + ConstantUrl.ID)
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Secured(value = { UserRoleString.ROLE_USER, UserRoleString.ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR, UserRoleString.ROLE_CONSULTATION })
 public void addModifiedFeature(@Context final HttpServletRequest request, @PathParam("id") final Long id, @QueryParam("layerId") Long layerId,  @QueryParam("featureId") Long featureId, @QueryParam("typeModif") Long typeModif) {
  try {
   
   ModifiedFeature modifiedFeature = mapService.addModifiedFeature(id, layerId, featureId, typeModif);
   
   OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
         OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.data(ModifiedFeature.class, modifiedFeature)
             .build();
         listSseBroadcaster.get(id).broadcast(event);
  } catch (OmeServiceException e) {
   UtilFacadeException.dealWithOmeServiceExceptionFacade(e);   
  }
 }
 
 @GET
 @Path("/sseEvents" + ConstantUrl.ID)
 @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
 @Secured(value = { UserRoleString.ROLE_USER, UserRoleString.ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR, UserRoleString.ROLE_CONSULTATION })
 public EventOutput getEventClient(@Context final HttpServletRequest request, @PathParam("id") Long id){
   final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
   
   if(listSseBroadcaster.get(id) == null){
    registerRoom(id);
   }
   
   listSseBroadcaster.get(id).add(eventOutput);
   return eventOutput;
 }
 
 public static void registerRoom(Long id) {
  listSseBroadcaster.put(id, new SseBroadcaster());
 }
}
```

I thinks something is missing to my project. How can i solve the problem?

Comment: You can't use Jersey 2 stuff with jersey 1

Comment: Thanks. I think that's the problem.